# Error while inserting image in fckeditor

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fckeditor

I see the following error whenever I insert an image into the fckeditor. I am running on Rails 2.3.8 and using the [easy_fckeditor plugin](https://github.com/gramos/easy-fckeditor)

```
Error This page can't be displayed. Contact support for additional
information. The incident ID is: 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the permission setting of Rails root folder